# Causes for slow build times of visual studio resource (.resx) files when using build solution in an asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, build-process, embedded-resource

I am working with an asp.net website and the App_LocalResources folders are very slow to compile.  Could there be a problem with the resource files  (.resx) files that would cause this?  My language files (English and French) are reasonably small.  No failures / exceptions are experienced.

Comment: Facing something similar. any one who can help?